# Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ a subset of $V$. Suppose zero is in $W$ and $W$ is closed under addition. Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that the answer to this question is No. My question is why is the answer no? What's missing?

if possible give a specific example of both $V$ and $W$ such that $W$ satisfies above conditoins but it is NOT a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is not simply "no" because it could be the case.

The answer to if it guarantees that its a subspace however, is indeed no.

Consider the basic example using $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Consider the space W consisting of vectors of the form $v=(x,y,z)$ such that all $x,y$ and $z$ are integers. So of course the zero vector is in W

say $v_1,v_2 \in W$ where $v_1=(3,2,3)$ and $v_2=(1,3,4)$ then $v_1+v_2 \in W$ but $\frac{1}{3} v_1= (1,\frac{2}{3},1)$ $\notin W$. i.e., this is not a subspace. even though it is a subset and the other two properties hold.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Not to spoil the answer with any words let me add here that the reason this  is not a subspace is that it is not closed under scalar multiples. If you would consider vectorspaces over a field with prime cardinality then additively closed is in fact sufficent.

Answer (score 1):

Integers, as a subset of real numbers. Clearly this is not a real subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:  Let $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $W=\{(n,m):n,m\in\Bbb Z\}$.  $W$ is certainly closed under addition, contains $(0,0)$, but it is not closed under scalr multiplication.  For example, $\frac12(1,1)\notin W$.